# Spinner no longer selects value when tapping empty space

Tags: android, spinner

Since I upgraded to Android 8.0 (26), I noticed that my spinners behave differently. The dropdown items are much smaller and most of all, tapping the empty space next to the text no longer causes the value to be selected, I have to tap on the actual text. This was not the case with Android 6.0 (23), where the dropdown items were larger and tapping the empty space also selected the value.

I noticed that this problem only occurs when I populate my spinner manually by setting an adapter from code, and not when I use `android:entries="@array/...` in the XML layout file.

I used the debugger in Android Studio and I can see that the value of `mDropDownResource` of the adapter is `17367049` for the spinners where the problem occurs, which is the value of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`. For the spinners where the values are set in XML this value is `2131492931`, so apparently when setting the values in XML a different layout/adapter/whatever is being used, and I can't figure out how to solve this problem.

This is the code I use to populate my spinner:

`ArrayAdapter<String> tagAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tags);
tagAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sTag.setAdapter(tagAdapter);`

This project has `compileSdkVersion` 28, `minSdkVersion` 26, `targetSdkVersion` 26 and uses the AppCompat library.

[image: OK]

[image: Not OK]

I made these screenshots on a Huawei P20 Lite. Strangely, when I run the same project on an emulator with the same API level the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: use custom adapter with your own row height with as per your need

Comment: But why does this only occur when setting an adapter and not when using entryValues? Can't I just make the ArrayAdapter use the same layout as entryValues uses? It always worked fine since I upgraded to O... I feel like there may be something else I'm doing wrong but I can't figure it out.

Comment: can you please show the screenshot of spaces?

Comment: @MiteshMachhoya I added screenshots. You can clearly see that the dropdown of the second spinner is smaller. Tapping the empty space next to the items doesn't select the value.

Comment: It also only works properly when `android:entries` is used **and** the activity extends AppCompatActivity. When I just use Activity it never works properly. Any ideas on this?